# Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials for user.name"

Tags: authentication, ldap, gitlab

I use

- debian 9
- gitlab-ce 11.10.4-ce.0
- omnibus install via apt
- openldap 2.4.44

`ldap` configuration

Configured `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` :

```
BASE    dc=serverX,dc=lan
URI     ldap://serverX.lan
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Configured `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` :

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS
  label: 'Gitlab LDAP'
  host: '10.0.0.1'
  port: 389
  uid: 'sAMAccountName'
  method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
  bind_dn: 'cn=admin,ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan'
  password: 'xxxx'
  encryption: 'plain'
  active_directory: false
  allow_username_or_email_login: true
  block_auto_created_users: false
  base: 'ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan'
EOS
```

Output of `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` is OK :

```
# gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

Users created from [phpldapadmin](/questions/tagged/phpldapadmin) :

[image]

Searched tons of web ressources, but I can't figure out the way to create LDAP users or use existing ones.

I don't know what is the issue and why I get `Invalid credentials for user.name` : I edited via `phpladmin` the `Password` attribute (`md5`) and I type the same one in the LDAP Gitlab login page :

[image]

Gitlab logs :

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started POST "/users/auth/ldapmain/callback" for 10.0.0.1 at 2019-05-16 07:56:16 +0200
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"user.name", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Redirected to http://domainX.lan/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 411ms (ActiveRecord: 23.1ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.0.1 at 2019-05-16 07:56:17 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 119ms (Views: 104.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
I, [2019-05-16T07:56:16.907169 #3996]  INFO -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2019-05-16T07:56:16.917884 #3996] ERROR -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::LDAP::InvalidCredentialsError, Invalid credentials for user.name
```

The `slapcat` output with targeted user to login :

```
dn: uuid=gquenot,ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan
cn:: abcdef123456789==
sn: Foo Bar
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: 5133fc-0be-2039-9825-cd7
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan
createTimestamp: 20190516045340Z
userPassword:: xxxxxxxx
mail: me@example.com
entryCSN: 20190516101837.136599Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan
modifyTimestamp: 20190516101837Z
```

Anyone knows what's wrong ?

Maybe someone can give me a sample `ldiff` and a working configuration ?

### Edit:

`slapadd` try with this `ldiff` via `slapadd -f file.ldiff` :

```
dn: cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Firstname Lastname
givenName: Gilles
sn: Quenot
uid: gquenot
mail: me@example.com
userPassword: {MD5}xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Error :

```
5cdd8fe4 slapcat_so.txt: line 1: unknown directive <dn:> outside backend info and database definitions.
slapadd: bad configuration file!
```

### Edit2

Fixed with :

```
ldapadd -x -H ldap://serverX:389 -D 'cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan' -W -f stuff.ldiff
```

And updated password in `phpldapadmin`

Comment: Did you try to fix the parameters or you really authenticate against AD ? What is the output of the cmd `ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.1:389 -D <user.name dn> -W -b <user.name dn> -s base *`?

Comment: Output error: `ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34) additional info: invalid DN`, but please, take a look to my added `slapcat` output. Changed config accordingly to `slapcat` output

Comment: So you tried with dn entry from the slapcat output replacing <user.name dn> by `cn=Company,ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan` ? But is it the ldap manager account? Because I was expecting a user with a *uid* attribute that is also used as the rdn to build its dn... This is the case by default in openLDAP for regular users, but if you use *cn* as identifier instead of uid you need to map 'uid' to 'cn' in gitlab config but I think it's not the issue. Also you changed 'base' to something wrong, it should contain a base dn under which you can find all the users you need to login, like the previous one.

Comment: Edited `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (check `bind_dn` & `base` ). The command `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` display no users, but can bind to LDAP

Comment: That means bindn and password are ok, but your 'base' points to a leaf (cn=...) in the ldap tree so it' wrong, it should be `ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan`. Also to be sure you have a "regular" with uid attribute try to createit with the ldif example I provided.

Comment: I get `line 1: unknown directive <dn:> outside backend info and database definitions` for `slapadd -f slapcat_so.txt`

Comment: Added sample ldiff and `slapadd` error

Comment: `slapadd` operates on the database and even though it should do the trick I'm less familiar with it, use `ldapadd` like described in the answer instead. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193481/discussion-between-ericlavault-and-gilles-quenot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Gitlab configuration targets Active Directory while you are using OpenLDAP to authenticate users, so the first thing to do is fixing the following parameters in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
uid: 'uid'
active_directory: false
```

I don't know what is the purpose of `attributes` in the context of an authentication (edit: `attributes` are used to synchronize user data from ldap to its Gitlab account, it shouldn't matter for the authentication itself).

Maybe there are other issues like the user's uid not being 'user.name', or the base being too narrow for example (user.name entry may not be under `ou=people`), if you don't know use the base dn as base search, or check by running a search with/without the 'ou' part :

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.1:389 -D cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan -W -b ou=people,dc=serverX,dc=lan uid=user.name \*
```

I'd also check the credentials themselves directly against ldap , ie. not through Gitlab, by performing roughly the same query but using *user.name* bindings, here we actually tests that he can bind and read its own entry :

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.1:389 -D <user.name dn> -W -b <user.name dn> -s base \*
```

Also GitLab documentation insists on the fact that *LDAP users must have an email address set, regardless of whether it is used to log in.*

A typical ldif file containing user.name entry to be created using `ldapadd -f` (provided that the ou and dc's mentioned in its distinguished name exists) would look like this :

```
# user.name entry 
dn: uid=user.name,ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Firstname Lastname
givenName: Firstname
sn: Lastname
uid: user.name
mail: user.name@domain.com
userPassword: {MD5}<base64EncodedHash>
```

I don't know though if/how GitLab is aware of the password encryption scheme (seems there is no config for this or I missed it).

---

You can create a test case entry :

- replace the `<base64EncodedHash>` with `{MD5}CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==` (it represents the password `test`, if you need I have a script to generate them).
- don't forget also to replace the dc's with the real ones in the dn
- beware of empty lines and \t in the ldif file as it can break your ldap add/modify operations.
- run `ldapadd -x -H ldap://10.0.0.1:389 -D cn=admin,dc=serverX,dc=lan -W -f ldifFilename` to create the user entry.
- running the 1st ldapsearch cmd above, you should see a result for that new entry.
- running the second one, binding with the user credentials 'test' and searching for its own entry (hence the -b base parameter pointing to himself to avoid permission issues during search), you should again see the same result.

In gitlab.rb :

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS
  label: 'Gitlab LDAP'
  host: '10.0.0.1'
  port: 389
  uid: 'uid'
  bind_dn: 'cn=admin,ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan'
  password: 'xxxx'
  encryption: 'plain'
  active_directory: false
  allow_username_or_email_login: false
  block_auto_created_users: false
  base: 'ou=users,dc=serverX,dc=lan'
```

If you can bind with this user but not through gitlab ui, that could mean it does not handle the {MD5} authentication scheme.

---

@see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/

Comment: Day saver, BIG UP, logged via LDAP <3

Comment: #!/bin/:)  .. and don't forget to uncomment the attributes in gitlab.rb for the synchronization to take effect !

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. Which synchronization do you mean ?

Comment: This is explained here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html, the config maps gitlab user settings like 'username' to the possible matching attribute  in your directory that contains the *corresponding* user data that you *need* to sync (don't bother if you don't need it!), but still note that username and email are mandatory for the sync and the account auto creation to work in gitlab. It's safe to copy/paste values from the doc as it covers the usual mapping for AD and openldap.

Comment: Yes, thanks, needed to match old user with LDAP ones

Comment: Page no longer exists @EricLavault! :(

Comment: @EricTobias Thanks to point it out, I added the updated link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem - Invalid credentials even though I was keying in the correct credentials.
This solution worked for me -
My gitlab.rb had to be changed in this manner below. Previously I had not changed the value of 'uid' which was set to 'sAMAccountName', as you can see I commented it
and changed the value to 'uid' itself. So  'uid' => 'uid' is the setting. Prior to doing this setting even when I was running the command -
gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check , The output used to show - LDAP authentication... Success
but no list of ldap users were shown.
As soon as I changed the uid value as above, the rake command worked smoothly and showed me the list of all ldap users in the dc. Post this I was able to login also into the application through the UI

Note - Replace all the XXX with your own values.

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
'main' => {
  'label' => 'LDAP',
  'host' =>  '10.XXX.XX.XX',
  'port' => 389,
#  'uid' => 'sAMAccountName',
  'uid' => 'uid',#mandatory need to keep the value as 'uid' only
  'encryption' => 'plain',
  'verify_certificates' => false,
  'bind_dn' => 'cn=XXX,dc=XXXX,dc=XXX',
  'password' => 'XXX',
  'verify_certificates' => false,
#  'tls_options' => {
#    'ca_file' => '',
#    'ssl_version' => '',
#    'ciphers' => '',
#    'cert' => '',
#    'key' => ''
#  },
  'timeout' => 10,
  'active_directory' => false,
  'allow_username_or_email_login' => false,
  'block_auto_created_users' => false,
  'base' => 'dc=XXX,dc=XX',
#  'user_filter' => '',
#  'attributes' => {
#    'username' => ['uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName'],
#    'email' => ['mail', 'email', 'userPrincipalName'],
#    'name' => 'cn',
#    'first_name' => 'givenName',
#    'last_name' => 'sn'
#  },
  'lowercase_usernames' => true,

  # EE Only
#  'group_base' => '',
#  'admin_group' => '',
#  'external_groups' => [],
#  'sync_ssh_keys' => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I install GitLab using Docker Engine
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html

LDAP Configuration
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/#integrate-ldap-with-gitlab

sudo docker exec -it gitlab nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
## LDAP Settings
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ldap.html
##! **Be careful not to break the indentation in the ldap_servers block. It is
##!   in yaml format and the spaces must be retained. Using tabs will not work.**

 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false

##! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: 'ipa.example.com'
     port: 636
     uid: 'uid'
     bind_dn: 'uid=gitlab,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com'
     password: 'gitlabpassword'
     encryption: 'simple_tls' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: false
     smartcard_auth: false
     active_directory: false
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     lowercase_usernames: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com'
     user_filter: ''
EOS
```

Save configuration, and than reconfigure GitLab:

```
 sudo docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash
    
 root@gitlab:/# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
 root@gitlab:/# gitlab-ctl restart
```

Check if LDAP integration works:

```
root@gitlab:/# gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
not verifying SSL hostname of LDAPS server 'ipa.example.com:636'
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
        DN: uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com       uid: admin
        DN: uid=gitlab,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com      uid: gitlab

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```